# Use property of Cauchy sequence to prove the convergence of the recurrence sequence

Tags: convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations, cauchy-sequences

Given the fact that $0 < \alpha < 1$, the sequence $(a_n)$ satisfies
$$ \lvert{a_{n+2} - a_{a+1}}\rvert \leq \alpha\lvert{a_{n+1}} - a_{n}\rvert,\quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.$$
then $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence and hence convergent.

How can I use this information to show that the sequences
$$a_1 = 0,\, a_2 = 1$$
$$a_n = \frac{1}{3} a_{n-1}+\frac{2}{3}a_{n-2}$$
and
$$c_1=1, c_{n+1} = \frac{3+2c_n}{3+c_n}$$
are convergent?
I have difficulties in proving the sequence satisfy the given inequality, I think use induction is possible but I have no idea how can I start..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

For $ (a_n)$.

we have

$$3a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+2a_n$$

thus

$$3(a_{n+2}-a_{n+1})=-2(a_{n+1}-a_n)$$

So,
$$\alpha=\frac 23$$

For the sequence $ (c_n) $, use the canonical form

$$c_{n+1}=2-\frac{3}{3+c_n}$$

Comment: For $(c_n)$, how can I ensure that $c_{n+2} - c_{n+1} \leq c_{n+1} - c_n$?
However, what is the meaning of canonical form?

Comment: @eulerisgod You should, as you said, begin by proving inductively that $ c_n>0$ to conclude that $\frac{1}{3+c_n}<\frac 13.$

Comment: Thanks for the hints! I have finished the question:)